# Compare JSON files and Update

Tags: php, json, diff

I will like to inquire if there are any tools out there specifically in [php](http://www.php.net/) that could do  something like this comparing two [json](http://www.json.org/) files for differences and update the new version with the old one ? btw, i tried php's [array_diff*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and they only give differences in one dimension. If there is someone out there who already did something similar, i will appreciate some pointers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380785/comparing-json-arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use a recursive array_diff?

```
function arrayRecursiveDiff($aArray1, $aArray2) {
  $aReturn = array();

  foreach ($aArray1 as $mKey => $mValue) {
    if (array_key_exists($mKey, $aArray2)) {
      if (is_array($mValue)) {
        $aRecursiveDiff = arrayRecursiveDiff($mValue, $aArray2[$mKey]);
        if (count($aRecursiveDiff)) { $aReturn[$mKey] = $aRecursiveDiff; }
      } else {
        if ($mValue != $aArray2[$mKey]) {
          $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue;
        }
      }
    } else {
      $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue;
    }
  }
  return $aReturn;
}
```

the function is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876435/recursive-array-diff)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It works. But i was expecting to update the new json file to the old one after detecting this differences.